# AWS CodePipeline - Code Deploy to S3 uncompressed artifact size limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I have a simple AWS code pipeline that builds a Gatsby site and creates a compressed artifact with around ~3.2GB. When moving to code deploy it fails with the following message,

[image]

Is there an option to increase the limit or any workarounds to upload the artifact to S3 and unzip it?

Following are the code pipeline steps,

[image]

Deploy stage configuration,

[image]

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/limits.html - 'These quotas are fixed and cannot be changed. ' Have you considering using a codebuild project to do an s3 upload of the file rather than a pipeline deploy action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this command in your buildspec.yaml in codebuild stage itself

`aws s3 cp --recursive ./build s3://AWS_S3_BUCKET​/`

Comment: For future references: https://github.com/jariz/gatsby-plugin-s3/issues/258